# book recommendation about iterative functional equations

Tags: functional-equations, book-recommendation

I would like to learn about **iterative functional equations**.

I read [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486445232) book, but it doesn't include such functional equations. I tried [this](https://books.google.gr/books/about/Iterative_Functional_Equations.html?id=IM7cdgtodqUC&redir_esc=y), but it was too general for my purpose. Finally I read [this](https://www.msri.org/people/staff/levy/files/MCL/Efthimiou/100914book.pdf), witch suggests [that](https://books.google.gr/books/about/On_Functions_and_Functional_Equations.html?id=eFMK8z2rt84C&redir_esc=y) book.

I tried to find a free copy of *Smital*, but I couldn't. So:

- is there a *copy of that book*?
- is there any *book like that*?
- is there any *book about iterative functional equations*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not the full book, but I think it has the required chapter. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eFMK8z2rt84C&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Smital%22&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJlrSmmsrmAhVShlwKHUq0BK8Q6AEILjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Extended , I 've seen it. You can see only the first 14 pages of the book. None of them is at the chapter "iterations".

Comment: http://ftp.math.uni-rostock.de/pub/romako/heft64/berg64.pdf, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e44d/57cbbfbad310764e31fdfb39584a7003a856.pdf